# Understanding Android BLE ScanSettings parameters

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

The documentation around [ScanSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings) is very laconic and I'm having a hard time coming up with an optimal configurations.

My requirements dictate I should report a new advertisement packet that matches my filter criteria (filtered on service UUIDs) as soon as possible. Duplicate advertisement packets are of no use to me. The advertisement packets will change when the peripheral will register an event on its side and the advertisement packet is thus an opportunity for me to detect changes and act accordingly. I also need to know when the peripheral stopped advertising (powered off or not in range anymore).

I've tried to set the callback type like following:

```
setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH | ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST)
```

The documentation for this parameters says:

> int CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES
>
> Trigger a callback for every Bluetooth advertisement found that matches the filter criteria. If no filter is active, all advertisement packets are reported.
>
> int CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH
>
> A result callback is only triggered for the first advertisement packet received that matches the filter criteria.
>
> int CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST
>
> Receive a callback when advertisements are no longer received from a device that has been previously reported by a first match callback.

I was hoping with this to get notified when the peripheral becomes available and then get notified when the peripheral is lost. However this doesn't trigger any scan results, at least not on my Pixel 2. So I just switched to use `CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES` and now I get all the advertisement packets. This is probably what I want anyways if I want to get updated packets from the same peripheral.

I looked at the `setMatchMode` parameters and it appears that this only configures the callbacks rate based on the signal strength:

> int MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE
>
> In Aggressive mode, hw will determine a match sooner even with feeble signal strength and few number of sightings/match in a duration.
>
> int MATCH_MODE_STICKY
>
> For sticky mode, higher threshold of signal strength and sightings is required before reporting by hw

The `setNumOfMatches` claims to handle the number of advertisements per filter, but none of the documented parameters seem to make a difference, I still get a burst of packets from the same peripheral that didn't change, seemingly at about the same rate no matter the parameter.

To meet the part of my requirement where I need to determine if the peripheral stopped advertising (powered off or not in range) I came up with a timestamp of last seen packet from the peripheral and determine if the peripheral is lost or not when I don't see a packet for x amount of seconds. This was necessary because the `CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH` and `CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST` don't seem to work at all.

This unfortunately means I get bursts of similar packets triggering a chain reaction in my code that I now have to deal with.

How can I configure the scanning so that I get notified only when the advertisement packet changes or the peripheral stopped advertising? Am I missing something here, or that's just not possible.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Same issue here. Any updates?

Comment: The way I've solved it was to implement my own packet filter that runs right at the discovery and throttle the callbacks myself.

The behaviour of this APIs aren't consistent across OS versions and OEMs unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had to implement reacting to a device that stops advertising (updating a list of available BLE devices). The majority of my testing was also done on the Pixel 2.

I'm not sure you can receive a callback upon advertisement package change for a peripheral *AND* receive a callback when a peripheral stops advertising, although I have not tested this.
To receive a callback when the device stops advertising and stop the bombardment of callbacks for every packet, use :

Kotlin:

```
private val bleScanSettings =
            ScanSettings.Builder().setCallbackType((ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH or ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST)).build()
```

Java:

```
ScanSettings bleScanSettings = new ScanSettings().Builder.setCallbackType((ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_FIRST_MATCH | ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_MATCH_LOST)).build();
```

My code is in Kotlin, the Java code is what I think it should be and looks identical to yours. This configuration will trigger an error callback when scanning without a `ScanFilter`, could that be your original issue?

This configuration will trigger a callback upon receiving the first matching advertisement packet for a device as well as when a matched device stops advertising.

You could try to see if the matching callback is also triggered when the advertisement packet for a (previously matched) device changes. Otherwise, it seems impossible.

Comment: did you actually try this before suggesting it works? becuase as OP and the others upvoting suggest, Match Lost never get triggered no matter what you do.

If you found some way to get it to work, Im sure everyone would like to know.
But merely decaring the MatchLost flag does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Set code like this:

```
  new ScanSettings.Builder ()
                 .setScanMode (ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED)
                 .setCallbackType (ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
                 .build (),...
```

This setting works on all devices. But each smartphone gives you a different error and this causes confusion.